# Prevent grouped components from splitting due to responsiveness

Tags: wix

To be able to create a table with columns of different colors, I found the only way was to create several single column tables and put them together. However, on mobile, since they are different tables, they split (due to responsiveness) and end up one above the over, so it breaks the concept of being a table, which ends up being useless.

I am using the Wix site builder.

Comment: This is a question for Wix technical support.  I have voted for it to be closed

Comment: I don't think this can be answered with the information that is provided.   Can you include some screenshots of this process from the Wix site builder to illustrate what you have done?